# Interesting real-life examples of functions with multivariable range

Tags: soft-question

The ones I can think of right now:

1. Location of a person
2. Temperature at every latitude and longitude (all looked at once)

I can think of more examples but they are just - calculating one quantity for several things or at several places.

What are some other interesting examples of concepts that are inherently multivariable?

I realise that this is way too open ended for Math Stack Exchange, but I don't know where else to ask it.

Comment: By "multivariable range" do you simply mean that it has multiple arguments? Then the entire supervised machine learning.

Comment: Consider not just position but time too as a variable

Comment: @Dmitry No no, I mean something like $f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1+x_2, sin(x_1), cos(x_2))$

Comment: imagine (at a fixed instant of time) the velocity of "every single" particle of air. This can be described as a function $\phi:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3$, where for every point $p \in\Bbb{R}^3$, $\phi(p)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ describes the velocity (at that fixed instant of time) of the air particle which is at location $p$

Comment: This is also called a vector field on $\Bbb{R}^3$. More generally, any vector field example from physics can answer your question (eg. the classical gravitational, electric and magnetic fields)